# How to get the count of a join table in sql server?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am working with an existing sql server statement:

```
select 
    rs.record_StepID, rs.recordID, rs.stepTypeID, 
    rs.label, rs.assignedToUserID, rs.stepActivatedDate,
    si.scheduledInspectionID, 
    l.streetNo, l.streetName, l.unit, l.city, l.state, 
    l.postalCode, l.country, rt.categoryName 
from 
    Record_Steps as rs 
left join 
    Users as u on rs.assignedToUserID = u.userID 
left join 
    ScheduledInspections as si on rs.record_StepID = si.record_StepID 
left join 
    Records as r on r.recordID = rs.recordID 
left join 
    Locations as l on l.locationID = r.locationID 
left join 
    recordTypes as rt on r.recordTypeID = rt.recordTypeID 
where  
    (rs.stepTypeID = 1 and rs.status = 1 and rs.assignedToUserID = '3200') 
    or 
    (rs.stepTypeID = 6 and rs.status = 1 and rs.assignedToUserID = '3200') 
    or 
    (rs.stepTypeID = 4 and rs.status = 1  and si.inspectorUserID = '3200' 
     and si.inspectionDate IS NOT NULL 
     AND CAST(si.inspectionDate AS DATE) <= CONVERT(DATE,'2014-9-8')) 
order by 
    stepActivatedDate asc
```

And all I need to do right now is to get the count of the records retrieved by this statement. I will need to set up a conditional to decide when to get a count and when to get the actual data but right now I need to get the count first, then after confirmation on the client side, get the data.

I am more familiar with mysql so I am looking to get something like `select count(*) from (select * from users)`, but any alteration that will allow me to get only the count as the return value from this statement would help me greatly.

I tried doing

```
select count(*) from ( <copy paste statement>)
```

to no avail.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work. I removed the `order by` from your derived table as it would cause an error and also gave the derived table an alias.

```
select count(1) as Cnt
from
(
    select rs.record_StepID, rs.recordID, rs.stepTypeID, rs.label, rs.assignedToUserID, rs.stepActivatedDate,si.scheduledInspectionID, l.streetNo,l.streetName, l.unit, l.city, l.state, l.postalCode, l.country, rt.categoryName 
    from Record_Steps as rs 
    left join Users as u on rs.assignedToUserID = u.userID 
    left join ScheduledInspections as si on rs.record_StepID=si.record_StepID 
    left join Records as r on r.recordID = rs.recordID 
    left join Locations as l on l.locationID = r.locationID 
    left join recordTypes as rt on r.recordTypeID = rt.recordTypeID 
    where (rs.stepTypeID = 1 and rs.status=1 and rs.assignedToUserID = '3200') 
    or (rs.stepTypeID = 6 and rs.status=1 and rs.assignedToUserID = '3200') 
    or (rs.stepTypeID = 4 and rs.status = 1  and si.inspectorUserID = '3200' and si.inspectionDate is not NULL and CAST(si.inspectionDate AS DATE) <= CONVERT(DATE,'2014-9-8')) 
)  as aTable
```

Comment: Wow this worked instantly. May I clarify a few things concept-wise and see if I'm right? you broke this down into select count(1) as cnt from myTable by giving it an alias aTable?

Comment: Yes. This is called a derived table.